# when taking the screen shot on .mm file not giving the output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am taking the screen shot on .mm file i used the below code
I tried in 2 ways it is not working.. If i place the same code in any one of my .m file its working

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    appDelegate.convertedImage=image;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

         (or)

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320, 416);//377
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    appDelegate.convertedImage=viewImage;
}
```

It is not works on .mm    Is there any other option to do?
(I integrated openCv in my project there i used 1 .mm file)

Please Guide me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` also. And did you try in `viewDidAppear:` ?

Comment: ok.. i tried.. in both the methods.... But not worked  @Aadhira

Comment: the image is not storing when i take the screen shot.. If i place the code in any of the other .m file instead of .mm it is working... In the both ways.... Do we need to change the code if we write in .mm ?file   @NSPostWhenIdle

Comment: Have you tried logging these methods to see if they're even being called?

Comment: yes.. i did those are calling.. i placed the break point also @NSPostWhenIdle

Comment: I tried for u. your code is working perfect. I think your code to store the image is having problem. lemme see where you are trying to stare your image after taken screen shot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewWillAppear method called before the view is rendered, so nothing to capture there. Have you tried using viewDidAppear instead?

[Some reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html).